# Trying to create a basic SSIS package that calls a web service with basic authentication

Tags: ssis

Trying to create a basic SSIS package that calls a web service with basic authentication and it is failing. The web service is deployed in apache tomcat and uses basic authentication configured in the web.xml file. I used SoapUI to test the Web service and it works fine. The client will be using SSIS and when I try to create the SSIS package, it returns a message

“The Web Service threw an error during method execution. The error is: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive..”

If I turn off authentication, the SSIS package works. I setup up the SSIS package using a HTTPConnectionManager, enter the credentials, added a WebServiceTask that uses the HTTPConnectionManager and the wsdl, output to file on the local drive. Is there something else I should do?  I am new to the SSIS world, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the package protection level set at?

Comment: EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey, this was the default, should I change it?

Comment: Nope, it's fine. If you had changed it to DontSaveSensitive, then you'd "lose" the user and password when you save. Just trying to eliminate possibilities

Comment: You said "If I turn off authentication" means that perhaps the credentials do not get passed through or erroneous or lacking some supplementary settings or info. Or may be you do not need any.

Comment: I found this post on MSDN. [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/775d16a9-0cd6-426a-80ad-b711328f2489/how-to-include-web-service-login-info-with-package) I am guessing that The connection manger only work with windows (domain) accounts, not apache accounts. So it looks like I will need to learn how to deploy the web server in IIS.forum=sqlintegrationservices)